# Remove rect(s) of specific colour from svg - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, jquery-svg

I have a chart which contains rectangles of two colours - purple and orange. I'm looking for a way to remove only the purple rectangles on a function call. How can I adapt;

```
 svg.selectAll("rect").remove()
```

For this purpse?

My rectangles are defined as;

purple rect

```
        .brush .extent {
            stroke: #DB4D94;
            fill-opacity: .125;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
```

orange rect

```
        .time-span {
            stroke: orange;
            fill-opacity: .7;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
```

These are both used to add different types of rectangles and the brush becomes a rectangle upon the function call - so don't worry about it not being recognized as a rect, it is!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [CSS attribute value selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp):

```
svg.selectAll("rect[stroke=purple]").remove();
```

Given that you're styling the rectangles using CSS classes, you may as well use those to select the element though:

```
svg.selectAll(".brush .extent").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give the purple rects a more unique class name like `.rect-purple` and then remove them

```
 svg.selectAll('.rect-purple').remove()
```

D3 selection works similarly to jQuery selection.